# XsltListViewWebPart and Content Deployment

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, content-deployment

I would like to know if there is a way to deploy (or migrate) an XsltListViewWebPart with a content deployment job ?

To explain further, I have two environments, "Authoring" and "Production", and I create the list view webparts using the well-know export process (SPD, "export", upload in WP gallery).
These webparts are used in the sub-sites to display lists and libraries located at the root site.
The thing is that if I don't specify the , I have the "list does not exist" error message, but then, it does not work in the destination site.
On the other end, the Destination site has to be created beforehand in order to create the content deployment path. Therefore, the site GUID will be different and if I want my webparts to work on the destination site, I have to adapt the  tag before running the deployment job.
And I would like to avoid the creation of webparts specific to the "Production" in the "Authoring" one.

Additionally, I played long time with the different elements of the .webpart file, ,  and , but none of the combination worked.

So, is there a way to solve this problem, creating a XsltListViewWebPart on an environment and using the content deployment jobs for the migration to another environment ?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Best Regards
Yves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you follow the instructions in the post below, which describes the process for deploying the data view webpart in 2007 (same problem, slightly different control).

- http://blog.solanite.com/keith/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3

You can also see within the members of the XsltListViewWebPart that it has the same ListName property described in post (distinct from the GUID)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.listname.aspx

Comment: Hello Neil,
Unfortunately, it seems that the XLVWP is enough different from the DVWP which does not make the first one to work anyway.
According to what I found today here :
http://www.intheknow.it/Default.aspx?Page=xsitexlverror&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
It sounds not possible to make it work correctly and I will probably have to go with the DVWP.
Thanks again.
Regards
Yves

Comment: I think you really need to look again at the MSDN piece. The XsltListViewWebPart inherits from the DVWP and so offers the same basic functionality.

Try following the instructions here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/11/10/easily-making-the-data-form-web-part-reusable.aspx

Try it for a basic DVWP and then carry across to an XLWVP. Would be interesting to find out if that works for you.

Comment: Indeed, the last link led me to a solution, even if I had to play a lot until I had something....
Thanks
Yves

Comment: Good stuff. Do you mind posting the code / additional sample for the benefit of others?